# Can't create a user in Rails 4.2 using AuthLogic

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authlogic

This is what I've tried, and I'm not sure where the problem is. . .

My model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic
  has_many :assignments
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string    :login,               :null => false               
      t.string    :crypted_password,    :null => false               
      t.string    :password_salt,       :null => false               
      t.string    :persistence_token,   :null => false               

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

This is what I'm getting in Rails console when trying to create a user:

```
 `<main>'2.2.0 :004 > User.create(login:'whatever', password:'1', password_confirmation:'1')
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."login") = LOWER('whatever') LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."persistence_token" = '4886c517de2414c730b7ed5cc296b0e19c3e56ee398fb0aeed0531c55cbb04fd2a8ce577a4d5bd7dbb52e46cf9ab5e27e287af0993a708d07ded12553460d11c' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => #<User id: nil, login: "whatever", crypted_password: "400$8$45$c054050d7ce04047$335b3dec54f141e7ab030e1f...", password_salt: "CQlMGatvdGngFXiogDcW", persistence_token: "4886c517de2414c730b7ed5cc296b0e19c3e56ee398fb0aeed...", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

No users are created after it:

```
  2.2.0 :005 > User.all
  User Load (61.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

No errors and some weird SQL. What could be the problem?

EDIT: Just tried `u = User.create(login:'whatever', password:'123', password_confirmation:'123'); u.errors.to_json`

And I got:

```
  => "{\"password\":[\"is too short (minimum is 4 characters)\"],\"password_confirmation\":[\"is too short (minimum is 4 characters)\"]}"
```

So that was my problem, password was too short. Too bad Rails didn't print it by default when I was seeding db. Thanks all!

Comment: If you can provide link to sample code we will be able to help you quickly

Comment: @Ecnalyr I think there is no record in table so it is unique

Comment: @Magnum I've just created an app, created User model and installed AuthLogic gem. Now I'm trying to create a user in Rails console. I've pasted all the relevant bits of code and I don't have anything else to show. Maybe you have any ideas on how to debug this stuff?

Comment: Check for validation errors, like u = User.create(login:'whatever', password:'1', password_confirmation:'1'); u.errors.to_json
And add them to question

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. Can you please post it as an answer so I can select it?